# How to flush post cache on new comment in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I use this code to clean post cache on saving post changes(on edit)

```
  after_commit :flush_cache
  def flush_cache
    Rails.cache.delete([self.class.name, id])
  end
```

When I add a new comment it doesn't apper in the comments div. But when I make some changes in this post, that comment appears.

How to flush post cache when a new post comment is added?

**up**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category, touch: true
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

.... validations.......

  scope :short_listed, -> {....long query here...}


  after_commit :flush_cache


  def self.cached_short_listed
    Rails.cache.fetch([name, "short_listed"], expires_in: 5.minutes) do
      short_listed.to_a
    end
  end

  def self.cached_find(id)
    Rails.cache.fetch([name,id], expires_in: 5.minutes){find(id)}
  end

  def flush_cache
    Rails.cache.delete([self.class.name, id])
    Rails.cache.delete([self.class.name, "short_listed"])
  end


  def cached_comments
    Rails.cache.fetch([self, "comments"]){comments.to_a}
  end

  def cached_category
    Category.cached_find(category_id)
  end

  def cached_user
    User.cached_find(user_id)
  end


end
```

Comment: can u please post your model where you have added the flush_cache method.

Comment: why do you actually need the rest of the model?

Comment: have u tried *after_save* callback instead of *after_commit*

Comment: also  post your comment model